# MySQL datetime versus datetime set in session. Which came first?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate whether the results i get from the database are made after the time set in session. However, it doesn't seem to work.

I set the time session like this:

```
$_SESSION['lastVisit'] = $user['lastVisit'];
```

Where $user['lastVisit'] is a datetime field in my database.

And i'm trying to select results from the database doing this:

```
if($unreadThreadsSql = $cms->db->query('SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE posted < ' . $_SESSION['lastVisit']))
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here, and would like your guys opinion. For reference, here's the entire code. I might just be doing something wrong somewhere.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->getUnread();
}

private function getUnread()
{
    global $cms;

    if($unreadThreadsSql = $cms->db->query('SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE posted < ' . $_SESSION['lastVisit']))
    {
        $forumSQL = $cms->db->query('SELECT * FROM forum_for');
        while($forums = $forumSQL->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $forumId = $forums['id'];
            $forumArray[$forumId] = $forums;
        }
        while($unreadThreads = $unreadThreadSql->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $forumId = $unreadThreads['forId'];
            $cms->db->query('INSERT INTO forum_unread(threadID, catID, forumID, userID, datetime, threadtime) VALUES('.$unreadThreads['id'].', '.$forumArray[$forumId]['cat_id'].','.$forumId.','.$_SESSION['userId'].',NOW(),'.$unreadThreads['posted'].' )');
        }
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the *value* of `$_SESSION['lastVisit']`? And shouldn't you be quoting the value, like:

```
"SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE posted > '" . $_SESSION['lastVisit'] . "'"
```

Comment: That worked. That's now burned into my brains. "Quote datetime".

Comment: @Dave, glad to hear it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE posted < ' . $_SESSION['lastVisit']
```

Shouldn't that be `> ' . $_SESSION['lastVisit']`?

Comment: Nope, there's still nothing being filled. I must've done something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @Dave: The code looks OK (with the `>` change). You need to debug a bit yourself to find the answer. For starters, look at the query SQL you execute by echoing it. Is the SQL correct? Does manually executing it give you any results?

Comment: Yep, it does seem the sql query was faulty, as the other answer suggested.